# I indeed add the file into .fsproj file, why the module cannot open?

Tags: f#

File Directory

```
src\
 App.fs
 App.fsproj
 typeProviders\
  chrome.fs
  DomComplement.fs
```

App.fsproj content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="./typeProviders/chrome.fs" />
    <Compile Include="./typeProviders/DomComplement.fs" />
    <Compile Include="App.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.Browser.Dom" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

chrome.fs:

```
module rec typeProviders.chrome
open System
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JS
open Browser.Types
open typeProviders.DomComplement
...
```

DomComplement.fs:

```
module rec typeProviders.DomComplement
open System
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JS
open Browser.Types
```

then IDE told me that:

[image]

I indeed add the DomComplement.fs file into App.fsproj file, why IDE cannot find the module?

After swapping the location of the two files in .fsproj, the module is still not recognized by IDE.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="./typeProviders/DomComplement.fs" />
    <Compile Include="./typeProviders/chrome.fs" />
    <Compile Include="App.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.Browser.Dom" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because `DomComplement` is included in the project file *after* `chrome`.

In F# the order of modules matters. Modules are compiled in the order they appear in the project file, and a module isn't available until it's compiled.

Just swap the `chrome` and `DomComplement` lines, and it will work.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Have you saved the project file? Reloaded the editor?

Comment: I restarted the IDE, but it still doesn't work